# Java DSE GraphFrame API does not fully support going from GraphTraversal to DataFrame

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise, datastax-java-driver, datastax-enterprise-graph

The Java DSE GraphFrame API does not fully support going from `GraphTraversal` to `DataFrame`.

The following `GraphTraversal` to `DataFrame` is possible:

```
gf().E().df()
```

**However this does not:**

```
gf().E().hasLabel("foo").df()
```

This is because `hasLabel()` returns a `GraphTraversal` instead of `com.datastax.bdp.graph.spark.graphframe.DseGraphTraversal` and `GraphTraversal` does not have the `df()` method.

This should be possible per the [docs](https://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/dse-graph-frame#Spark_GraphFrameJava_API)

> To finish a traversal and return to the DataFrame API instead of list
>   or iterator use the .df() method:
>
> graph.V().df()

I'm using `dse-graph-frames:5.1.4` along with `dse-byos_2.11:5.1.4`.

Is this expected? All I really want is to do some graph traversal and convert it into a DataFrame.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It works in Scala as is, in Java you need to add the cast to DseGraphTraversal

```
((DseGraphTraversal)gf.E().hasLabel("foo")).df()
```

I gave a longer answer here [Iterating a GraphTraversal with GraphFrame causes UnsupportedOperationException Row to Vertex conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48316620/iterating-a-graphtraversal-with-graphframe-causes-unsupportedoperationexception/48318972#48318972)