# Iterating a GraphTraversal with GraphFrame causes UnsupportedOperationException Row to Vertex conversion

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise, datastax-java-driver, datastax-enterprise-graph

The following

```
    GraphTraversal<Row, Edge> traversal = gf().E().hasLabel("foo").limit(5);
    while (traversal.hasNext()) {}
```

causes the following Exception:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Row to Vertex conversion is not supported: Use .df().collect() instead of the iterator

    at com.datastax.bdp.graph.spark.graphframe.DseGraphTraversal.iterator$lzycompute(DseGraphTraversal.scala:92)
    at com.datastax.bdp.graph.spark.graphframe.DseGraphTraversal.iterator(DseGraphTraversal.scala:78)
    at com.datastax.bdp.graph.spark.graphframe.DseGraphTraversal.hasNext(DseGraphTraversal.scala:129)
```

Exception says to use `.df().collect()` but `gf().E().hasLabel("foo")` does not allow you to do `.df()` afterwards. In other words, method `df()` is not there for object returned by `hasLabel()`

I'm using the Java API via `dse-graph-frames:5.1.4` along with `dse-byos_2.11:5.1.4`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer: You need to cast GraphTraversal to DseGraphTraversal that has df() method. Then use one of spark Dataset methods to collect Rows:

```
List<Row> rows =
   ((DseGraphTraversal)graph.E().hasLabel("foo"))
   .df().limit(5).collectAsList();
```

DseGraphFrame does not yet support full TinkerPop specification. So you can not receive TinkerPop Vertex or Edge objects. ( `limit()` method is also not implemented in DSE 5.1.x). It is recommended to switch to spark dataset api with df() call, get `Dataset<Row>` and use Dataset base filtering and collecting

If you need only Edge/Vertex properties you still can use TinkerPop `valueMap()` or `values()`

```
    GraphTraversal<Row, Map<String,Object>> traversal = graph.E().hasLabel("foo").valueMap();
    while (traversal.hasNext()) {}
```